An apparent contradiction between pylance and mypy
Consider the following class:
class CM:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def __enter__(self) -> CM:
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *_):
        ...

mypy reports no issues with this. However, pylance highlights the type hint and indicates "CM" is not defined.
Is this the correct way to type hint the return from __enter__ ? If yes then, presumably, pylance is flawed. Or is mypy wrong?
Is there another way to write this type hint that would satisfy both pylance and mypy

The name CM is technically not defined while the body of the class CM is being evaluated.
>>> class CM:
...   def foo() -> CM:
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in CM
NameError: name 'CM' is not defined
>>>

(This does work when PEP 563 postponed annotations are used, i.e. with from __future__ import annotations.)
typing.Self is more correct.
from typing import Self

class CM:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def __enter__(self) -> Self:
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *_):
        ...

